# converting images in a folder to new format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic

I am trying to convert a group of images in a folder to animated gif and facing error

> "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Also there must be error in display image as lable.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Variable declaration
    MemoryStream memoryStream;

    binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);

   int numFiles = fileEntries.Length;
    for (int picCount = 0; picCount < numFiles; picCount++)
    {
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileEntries[picCount]);

         image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
         buf1 = memoryStream.ToArray();

         memoryStream.SetLength(0);
    }
    binaryWriter.Close();
    System.Drawing.Image streamGIF = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
   Label1.Text += "<img src=" + streamGIF + " /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the image first on drive and then give its path to image tag.

```
System.Drawing.Image streamGIF = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
string imageName = "~/Images/test.gif";
string savePath = Server.MapPath(@"Images\test.gif");       
streamGIF.Save(savePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);           
binaryWriter.Close();
img1.ImageUrl = imageName;
```

Comment: Yes..but image is not displaying..problem is with streamGif which is System.Drawing.Bitmap file.

Comment: Getting error:"Error 1 The name 'img1' does not exist in the current context".I commented it and created a folder named Images.and had run the application but no image is created in this folder

Comment: Here I've taken img1  asp:image tag. You have to first create it in design.

Comment: Where did you create the folder? It should be with in your solution.

Comment: Yes i did created it in solution explorer.

Comment: Priya, Yes its working Thank You Very much in helping me in this problem.

Comment: Do one thing, move the binaryWriter.Close(); after the streamGIF.Save(). it will work.